# What do firebase cloud-storage read access rules apply to? SDK, URL http get, or both?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm new to firebase cloud storage.   Quick question: Are firebase cloud-storage read rules meant to apply to SDK read access, or http (get) URL access (via the URL returned by the SDK after a write), or both?

May have followup questions depending on how this question is answered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase security rules for Cloud Storage apply to users accessing Cloud Storage through the [Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start).

The rules do not apply to users accessing Cloud Storage through a download URL, which is an unguessable URL that provides read-only access to files.

The rules also do not apply to users accessing Cloud Storage through one of the native Cloud Storage SDKs, which run with administrative permissions and are typically only run on app servers or otherwise trusted environments.